# Time Series Analysis with variable input size for 1-D Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: time-series, classification, conv-neural-network

I want to apply Time Series Analysis with an ANN-approach. My first goal is to do a classification. My Data consist of variable input size. For example several data with size 380, several data with 450, etc.

I want to use a 1-D Convolutional Neural Network with the Framework Tensorflow. I know RNN are capable with variable input size, but I don’t want to use it. Because in a further step I want to implement an autoencoder with CNN.

So my question is, are there techniques for handling with the variable input size, instead of zero-padding. Are there some special CNN-techniques to handle this?

Thanks a lot.